# Create custom chat control for bot framework

Tags: api, artificial-intelligence, chat, bots, botframework

I'm using Microsoft [Bot emulator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/debug-bots-emulator) to test or debug the chat API developed via Bot framework.

Now, i'm going to host the service in my IIS server, but i would like to know how to write client application to this?. We cant use emulator in realtime, we need to provide user a chat window & enter button.

I'm not getting any example projects on how to create chat window for bot API. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you registered your bot on [Microsoft Bot Framework](http://dev.botframework.com) website yet?

When you are done with this process, there are plenty of channels (Facebook,Skype, etc.) to use in order to talk to your bot. One of them is a simple web client.

How to register a bot: [Register a bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/portal-register-bot)

How to connect your bot to channels: [Connect a bot to channels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/portal-configure-channels)

Answer (score 0):

If you would like a custom chat control please see the [WebChat control](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat).  It is an open source project you can customize and modify to suit your needs.  You can embed it anywhere you like.

Comment: hi, thanks, but i want to create the same control in .net, is this possible?

Comment: Yes you could create one in C# if you wanted to